# Exclude entries from being written to syslog

Tags: logging, syslog

**Question:**
I want a specific log message (pattern) to be written to syslog. How can I achieve that?

**Example:**
I imagine a solution like writing something like this in the appropriate logfile:

```
 exclude .*pipe.*
```

To prevent all messages containing "pipe" from being written to the log file. I'm not trying to change the log level. I'm trying to disable individual log entries.

**What I found so far:**
I found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/75896/is-there-any-way-to-exclude-specific-entries-from-linux-log-files), but it didn't really give an answer.

System: Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: You haven't given any release details, but you can change syslog level (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles though I don't know at what level that message gets thrown, nor what level you're at currently, let alone your release/kernel..)

Comment: guiverc, I rewrote the question. I hope it get's more clear now. The goal is to disable an individual log message.